# Removing elements from a node

Tags: ruby, dom, nokogiri

Given a `Nokogiri::XML::Node` object, how can I remove some of its dom nodes? For example, suppose I have an object whose `innerHtml` is:

```
hello world <b>this is in bold face</b> <div>this is inside a div</div> bye bye
```

How can I remove the `<div>` element and get a `Nokogiri::XML::Node` object whose `innerHtml` is:

```
hello world <b>this is in bold face</b>  bye bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `<div>` and call `remove` on it. For example:

```
>> node.to_html
=> "<div>hello world <b>this is in bold face</b> <div>this is inside a div</div> bye bye</div>"
>> node.at('div').remove; node.to_html
=> "<div>hello world <b>this is in bold face</b>  bye bye</div>"
```